# C++ - Vector Segmentation Error

Tags: c++, linux, g++, ubuntu-13.10, blackjack

I am currently working on a CMSC project called Blackjack for my college course. I have am trying to add a class called Card to a vector object in another class called Hand. The Hand class is stored as an object in another vector in a class called Player.

My issue is that I try to call the method OutputPlayerHand in a class called Blackjack but I get a segmentation error.

Here is my code for the Blackjack.cpp class.

```
#include "Blackjack.h"
#include <iostream>

Blackjack::Blackjack()
{
  // Initialize the dealer
  Player dealer((char *) "Dealer", 100);
  m_dealer = dealer;

  // Initialize a player 'Jane' with 100 funds
  Player player((char *) "Jane", 100);
  m_players.push_back(player);
}

Blackjack::Blackjack(char *names[], int numPlayers)
{
  // Initialize the dealer
  Player dealer((char *) "Dealer", 100);
  m_dealer = dealer;

  // Loop through all passed player names
  for(int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)
    {
      // Initialize a player 'names[i]' with 100 funds
      Player player(names[i], 100);
      m_players.push_back(player);
    }
}

int Blackjack::GetNumPlayers()
{
  // Return the size of the players vector
  return m_players.size();
}

char *Blackjack::GetPlayerName(int player)
{
  // Return the requested player's name
  return m_players[player].GetName();
}

int Blackjack::GetPlayerFunds(int player)
{
  // Return the requested player's funds
  return m_players[player].GetFunds();
}

void Blackjack::SetPlayerFunds(int player, int amt)
{
  // Set the requested player's funds
  m_players[player].SetFunds(amt);
}

bool Blackjack::SetPlayerBet(int player, int amt)
{ 
  // If the player has insufficient funds
  if(m_players[player].GetFunds() < amt)
    {
      // Return false
      return false;
    }

  // Subtract the amount from the player funds
  m_players[player].SetFunds(m_players[player].GetFunds() - amt);
  // Add the amount to the player bet
  m_players[player].SetBet(amt);
  // Return true
  return true;
}

void Blackjack::NewDeal()
{
  // Create a new unsorted 52 card deck
  Deck deck;
  // Initialize m_deck to the new deck
  m_deck = deck;
  // Shuffle m_deck
  m_deck.Shuffle();

  // 2 cards for dealer, 2 cards for each player
  int cardsToDeal = 2 + (2 * m_players.size());

  // While we still have cards to deal
  while(cardsToDeal > 0)
    {
      // Deal to each player
      for(unsigned int i = 0; i < m_players.size(); i++)
    {
      std::cout << "Deal Player Card" << std::endl;
      // Deal one card to the player
      m_players[i].GetHand().AddCard(m_deck.DealCard());
      // Decrement the number of cards to deal
      cardsToDeal--;
    }

      std::cout << "Deal Dealer Card" << std::endl;
      // Deal the dealer one card
      m_dealer.GetHand().AddCard(m_deck.DealCard());
      // Decrement the number of cards to deal
      cardsToDeal--;
    }
}

void Blackjack::OutputPlayerHand(int player)
{
  std::cout << "Player Output Card." << std::endl;
  m_players[player].GetHand().GetCard(0).OutputCard();
}

void Blackjack::OutputDealerHand()
{
  // TODO: Code Method
}

bool Blackjack::HitPlayer(int player)
{
  // TODO: Code Method
  return false;
}

void Blackjack::DealerPlay()
{
  // TODO: Code Method
}

int Blackjack::SettlePlayerBet(int player)
{
  // TODO: Code Method
  return -1;
}
```

Here is my code for the Player.cpp class.

```
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player()
{
  m_name = (char *) "Jane";
  m_funds = 100;
  m_bet = 0;
}

Player::Player(char *name, int funds)
{
  m_name = name;
  m_funds = funds;
  m_bet = 0;
}

char *Player::GetName()
{
  return m_name;
}

void Player::SetName(char *name)
{
  m_name = name;
}

int Player::GetFunds()
{
  return m_funds;
}

void Player::SetFunds(int funds)
{
  m_funds = funds;
}

int Player::GetBet()
{
  return m_bet;
}

void Player::SetBet(int bet)
{
  m_bet = bet;
}

Hand Player::GetHand()
{
  return m_hand;
}
```

Here is my code for the Hand.cpp class.

```
#include "Hand.h"

void Hand::AddCard(Card card)
{
  m_cards.push_back(card);
}

Card Hand::GetCard(int card)
{
  return m_cards[card];
}

int Hand::Size()
{
  return m_cards.size();
}

void Hand::Clear()
{
  m_cards.clear();
}
```

Here is my code for the main class Proj2.cpp.

```
/*
 * CHANGES TO Blackjack.h SPEC:
 *   added new member funcs:
 *     char *GetPlayerName(int)
 *     int GetNumPlayers()
 *     void OutputDealerHand()
 *
 *   HitPlayer() should print out the card that was dealt.
 */
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "Blackjack.h"

using namespace std;

Blackjack *CreateGame(int argc, char *argv[]);
int ProcessArgs(int argCnt, char *args[], char **&names, int *&funds);
void DoNewDeal(Blackjack &game);
void ProcAllBets(Blackjack &game);
void DoAllPlays(Blackjack &game);
void PlayOnePlayer(Blackjack &game, int player);
void SettleAllPlayers(Blackjack &game);
void ShowAllPlayerFunds(Blackjack &game);
bool QueryAnotherRound();


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Blackjack *game;
    int round;

    cout << "Welcome to CMSC 202 Blackjack!\n";
    game = CreateGame(argc, argv);

    round = 0;
    do {
    cout << "\nRound " << ++round << ":\n";
    ProcAllBets(*game);
    DoNewDeal(*game);
    DoAllPlays(*game);
    SettleAllPlayers(*game);
    ShowAllPlayerFunds(*game);
    } while (QueryAnotherRound());

    cout << "\nGoodbye!\n";
    return 0;
}


Blackjack *CreateGame(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char **names;
    int *funds;
    int numPlayers;
    Blackjack *game;

    numPlayers = ProcessArgs(argc - 1, &argv[1], names, funds);
    game = new Blackjack(names, numPlayers);
    for (int p = 0; p < numPlayers; p++) {
    game->SetPlayerFunds(p, funds[p]);
    }
    return game;
}


int ProcessArgs(int argCnt, char *args[], char **&names, int *&funds) {
    int i, p;
    int numRecs = argCnt / 2;

    names = static_cast<char **>(calloc(numRecs, sizeof(char *)));
    funds = static_cast<int *>(calloc(numRecs, sizeof(int)));

    for (p = 0, i = 0; p < numRecs; p++) {
    names[p] = args[i++];
    funds[p] = atoi(args[i++]);
    }
    return p;
}


void ProcAllBets(Blackjack &game) {
    int numPlayers = game.GetNumPlayers();
    int bet;

    for (int p = 0; p < numPlayers; p++) {
        cout << "How much does " << game.GetPlayerName(p) << " bet? ";
    cin >> bet;
    cout << endl;  // For neat scripting
    if (!game.SetPlayerBet(p, bet)) {
        cout << "Illegal bet--changing to $0\n";
        game.SetPlayerBet(p, 0);
    }
    }
}


void DoNewDeal(Blackjack &game) {
    int numPlayers = game.GetNumPlayers();

    game.NewDeal();
    cout << "The players' hands:\n";
    for (int p = 0; p < numPlayers; p++) {
    cout << game.GetPlayerName(p) << ": ";
    game.OutputPlayerHand(p);
    cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "Dealer: ";
    game.OutputDealerHand();  // This hides dealer's hole card
    cout << "\n\n";
}


void DoAllPlays(Blackjack &game) {
    int numPlayers = game.GetNumPlayers();
    int p;

    for (p = 0; p < numPlayers; p++) {
    PlayOnePlayer(game, p);
    }
    game.DealerPlay();
}

void PlayOnePlayer(Blackjack &game, int player) {
    char *name = game.GetPlayerName(player);
    string answer;
    bool hit, busted;

    cout << ">>" << name << "'s turn:\n";
    busted = false;
    do {
    cout << "Hand: ";
    game.OutputPlayerHand(player);
    cout << endl;

    cout << name << "'s play: ";
    cin >> answer;
    cout << endl;  // For neat scripting
    answer[0] == 'y' || answer[0] == 'Y';
    hit = (answer[0] == 'h' || answer[0] == 'H');
    if (hit) {
        busted = game.HitPlayer(player);
    }
    } while (hit && !busted);
    if (busted) {
    cout << "Busted!\n";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void SettleAllPlayers(Blackjack &game) {
    int numPlayers = game.GetNumPlayers();
    int p;

    for (p = 0; p < numPlayers; p++) {
    game.SettlePlayerBet(p);
    // Above should print out:
    //  Joe has busted--Dealer wins", or "Sally has 15--Dealer loses"
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void ShowAllPlayerFunds(Blackjack &game) {
    int numPlayers = game.GetNumPlayers();
    int p;

    for (p = 0; p < numPlayers; p++) {
    cout << game.GetPlayerName(p) << " now has $"
         << game.GetPlayerFunds(p) << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

bool QueryAnotherRound() {
    string answer;

    cout << "Another round? ";
    cin >> answer;
    cout << endl;  // For neat scripting
    return answer[0] == 'y' || answer[0] == 'Y';
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am not allowed to edit the Proj2.cpp class in any way. If you need more information please do not hesitate to ask. If you need to see the project in it's entirety [here](https://github.com/Terrablezach/Blackjack) is a link to the Github repository for the entire project so far. If you need to see my project rules and clarifications, [here](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/undergraduate/202/spring14/projects/project2/) is a link to my courses project description website.

Any help is greatly appreciated on this matter, thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Where does `m_hand` get set it your Player class? You probably also want to return it as a reference, not as a value, in GetHand too. You should try stepping into OutputPlayerHand in a debugger: chances are one of the pointers along the way is null or bad. If you can't use a debugger, you can e.g. put debug printf statements in to see which functions it's managing to step into, what the state is at that point, etc.

Comment: Also you're going the wrong way casting your string constants to `char*`: consider making your storage for them `const char*`. Better still, use `std::string` to store them which guarantees that you're taking a copy to store rather than relying on someone else's memory management of a stored pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The `Hand` is empty.

This line: `m_players[i].GetHand().AddCard(m_deck.DealCard())` adds a card to a temporary copy only
Make `GetHand()` return a reference and your players will actually get cards.

Also, you should not include executables like Prog2.out in repositories.